# "Amend" a git merge commit after the merged branch is changed

Tags: git, merge, squash

Suppose that I have merged a source branch to a destination branch in git. It took a lot of time to resolve the conflicts. In the meanwhile the source branch has changed a lot. Now I have to merge the latest state of the source branch into the destination branch, but I need to "amend" the first merge commit, so I only have one merge commit instead of two. How can I squash the two merge commits together?

Were they regular commits, I would do a soft reset to HEAD~, then commit --amend, but in this case this would result in merge2 having the wrong parents: it would not be derived from the last commit of the src branch. Rebasing also does not work as I don't know how to rebase a commit as a merge (i.e. making it have two specific parents). I also don't want to redo the whole merge from scratch as that would take a lot of time.

Is there a way I could do this in git?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. Suppose that the graph looks like that in the second figure (with "merge" and "merge2"). Then do this:

```
git replace --graft HEAD HEAD^^ HEAD^2
```

This changes the parents of HEAD to HEAD^^ and HEAD^2.

The first parent of a merge commit is always the destination branch, and the second parent is the source branch (the branch that was merged into the other one). HEAD^ is the first parent of HEAD (=merge2), which is the first merge commit, so HEAD^^ is the first parent of the first merge commit -- this should be the new first parent of the second merge commit! HEAD^2 is the second parent of merge2, which should be left unchanged. So changing the two parents of HEAD to HEAD^^ and HEAD^2 does the job.

Comment: Note: this changes what Git *sees*, but the underlying commits are still the same. The graft replacement is an overlay: a copy of commit "merge2" with a changed second parent, and hence a different hash ID. This extra copy has the name `refs/replace/<hash>` attached to it, where the hash is that of the original commit. When Git goes to find the original commit, it finds the `refs/replace/` name and, at the last moment, "moves its eyes" to the replacement instead of using the original.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with all of this, just be aware that transfer mechanisms (`git push` and `git fetch`) normally *ignore* the replacement entirely. If you get them to send the replacement too, they send it as a replacement. Other people won't obtain the replacement by default. So you may want to use `git filter-branch` afterward, to rewrite the original commits into a new history. Filter-branch obeys the replacements (at least by default) so a simple "copy what you see" copies the grafted graph.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A commit's hash should change if the parents change, since the parents are supposed to be included in the hash computation. So you cannot change the parents with the commit hash remaining the same, right?
Am I correct that the replacement commit is still a perfectly normal commit, but there exists a link from the old one to the new one, so whenever you want to query the properties of the old one, you will be redirected to the new one?

Comment: The graft copy is a new commit (with different hash), yes. But there is no linkage between the original (pre-graft) commit and the new graft commit. There is a `refs/replace/<hash>` *name* for the replacement commit, where the `<hash>` part of the *name* is the actual hash ID of the pre-graft commit. The `refs/replace/*` *references* aren't copied across clone and push by default, and hence neither are the replacement commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you think from another angle, it will be easy.
Let's say your main branch is called "branch-main" and your another branch called "branch-dev". What you need to do from figure 2 is (assuming you are on branch-main and your HEAD is at the merge node).

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git merge branch-dev
```

That's it. It will give you a new merge node ignoring the previous one, which is what figure 3 is.